# How to change single index value in level 1 in MultiIndex dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rename, multi-index

I have this MultiIndex dataframe, df after parsing some text columns for dates with regex.

```
df.columns
Index(['all', 'month', 'day', 'year'], dtype='object')
```

```
        all   month day year
  match             
456 0   2000    1   1   2000
461 0   16      1   1   16
    1   1991    1   1   1991
463 0   25      1   1   25
    1   2014    1   1   2014
465 0   19      1   1   19
    1   1976    1   1   1976
477 0   14      1   1   14
    1   1994    1   1   1994
489 0   35      1   1   35
    1   1985    1   1   1985
```

I need to keep the rows with years only (2000,1991,2014,1976,1994,1985). Most of these are indexed as 1 at level 1, except for the first one, (456,0).
so that I could handle them this way:

```
df=df.drop(index=0, level=1)
```

My result should be this.

```
        all   month day year
  match             
456 0   2000    1   1   2000
461 1   1991    1   1   1991
463 1   2014    1   1   2014
465 1   1976    1   1   1976
477 1   1994    1   1   1994
489 1   1985    1   1   1985
```

I have tried

```
df.rename(index={(456,0):(456,1)}, level=1, inplace=True)
```

which did not seem to do anything.

I could do df1=df.drop((456,1)) and df2=df.drop(index=0, level=1) and then concat them and remove the duplicates, but that does not seem very efficient?

I cant drop the MultiIndex because I will need to append this subset to a bigger dataframe later on.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is chain 2 masks by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df = df[(df.index.get_level_values(1) == 1) | (df.index.get_level_values(0) == 456)]
print (df)
        all  month  day  year
456 0  2000      1    1  2000
461 1  1991      1    1  1991
463 1  2014      1    1  2014
465 1  1976      1    1  1976
477 1  1994      1    1  1994
489 1  1985      1    1  1985
```

Another idea if need always first value is possible set array mask by index to `True`:

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 1
mask[0] = True

df = df[mask]
print (df)
        all  month  day  year
456 0  2000      1    1  2000
461 1  1991      1    1  1991
463 1  2014      1    1  2014
465 1  1976      1    1  1976
477 1  1994      1    1  1994
489 1  1985      1    1  1985
```

Another out of box solution is filtering not duplicated values by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html), working here because first value `456` is unique and for all another values need second rows:

```
df1 = df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df1)
        all  month  day  year
456 0  2000      1    1  2000
461 1  1991      1    1  1991
463 1  2014      1    1  2014
465 1  1976      1    1  1976
477 1  1994      1    1  1994
489 1  1985      1    1  1985
```

Comment: @Manakin - isin is not possible use here, because tested first and second level :(

Comment: @jezrael just tested and you are right! that's strange! I thought each record set would filter exclusively

Answer (score 1):

Another way. Query the level

```
df.query('match == [1]')



 match   all  month  day  year
461      1  1991      1    1  1991
463      1  2014      1    1  2014
465      1  1976      1    1  1976
477      1  1994      1    1  1994
489      1  1985      1    1  1985
```